# unity touch control with UI image

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, multi-touch, unityscript

I have a written a multi-touch system that works correctly with objects that have collider2d (use them as buttons) and i can move the player in my android phone.
But when i use an image from the UI canvas system and add this code to the image, it doesn't detect any thing ?!
here is my code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour {

public float jumpForce;
private GameObject hero; 

void Start () {
    hero = GameObject.Find("hero"); 
}

void Update () {

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch[] myTouches = Input.touches;
        for(int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
        {
            if(Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                CheckTouch(Input.GetTouch(i).position, "began");
            }
            else if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                CheckTouch(Input.GetTouch(i).position, "ended");
            }
        }

    }
}

void CheckTouch (Vector3 pos, string phase)
{

    Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos);
    Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2 (wp.x, wp.y);

    Collider2D hit = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos);

    if(hit.gameObject.name == "JumpButton" && hit && phase == "began")
    {
        hero.rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));  //Add jump force to hero
        audio.Play ();
    }
}
}
```

any help?

Answer (score 2):

For Graphics items in canvas you need to use GraphicRaycaster instead of Physics2D using UnityEngine.UI

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to work with touches yourself anymore. Just implement [IPointerClickHandler](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) interface and make sure you have EventSystem and an appropriate raycaster present in the scene.